# How can I make ios UDID shorter but still unique enlough

Tags: iphone, udid

I want to make the UDID of a iOS device to less than or equal to 15 characters.

I am porting a Symbian based client-server software to iOS. The server side uses IMEI (15 digits)to id a client phone. Now on iOS, UDID is too long(40 hex digits). As I want to minimize the change of server program or DB, I need to store the UDID in a varchar(15).

So it's there any way to make the UDID shorter but still unique enlough. It could be much better if I can also get the UDID from the shorted string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could convert the hex digits into 20 Latin-1 characters (≤0xff) or 10 Unicode [BMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Multilingual_Plane#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) characters (≤0xffff).

If that varchar(15) can accept Unicode BMP characters, then we are done.

Otherwise, you could chop the last 5 characters from that 20 Latin-1 characters. The UDID is in fact a [SHA-1 hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) of some device-unique values, which can be considered quite random and the digits are uniformly distributed. Therefore, with 15 Latin-1 characters the reduced UDID should be able to represent 256<sup>15</sup> ~ 10<sup>36</sup> devices, which is much more than enough.

In fact, even if you just take 15 hex characters from the UDID it could already represent ~ 10<sup>18</sup> devices.

Note that the last 2 methods are lossy, i.e. there is no way you could get the complete UDID from the 15 characters.

Comment: Hi, I have a problem with the solution, as I need to pass data to server via a txt file, which use /r/n to separate rows and colon to separate columns. so my problem is what if the ASCII or Unicode char happens to be a colon, a /r or something not going to display on screen. For example, in ASCII, 0x08 is backspace, 0x1C is file separator, things like that. So what happens if the shorted UDID happens to have a character like that?

Comment: @Zhao: You could use base-64 encoding of a portion of the UDID. Of course, this can only represent 64^15 ~ 10^27 devices.

Comment: Thank you. That is truly a genius ideal to encode it. I think I'll use CRC-32 as it results 8 hex digits. The only pity it's I cannot get the UDID back. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I just wrote this gist -> https://gist.github.com/3996097

What do you think about a CFUUID + sha1 + substring + random uppercase ?

```
//Get a random hash (Generated from CFUUID+sha1)
NSString *hash = [NSString sha1:[NSString getUUID]];

//Shorten the sha1
NSString *short_random_id = [hash substringFromIndex:[hash length]-10];

//Random uppercase / lowercase the id
NSMutableString *random_id_final = [NSMutableString string];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [short_random_id length]; i++)
{
    NSString *substring = [short_random_id substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
    [random_id_final appendString:(rand() % 2) ? [substring lowercaseString] : [substring uppercaseString]];
}
```