# Trade offs of using long keyname vs. intensive queries

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I currently have the following model structure (only the relevent ones pasted below):

```
class userData(ndb.Model): 
    uuId = ndb.StringProperty()
    fId = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    name = ndb.StringProperty()
    email = ndb.StringProperty()
    gender = ndb.BooleanProperty()
    age = ndb.StringProperty()
    created = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    lastUpdate = ndb.DateTimeProperty()

class responses(ndb.Model):
    pId = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=shoes2)
    uuId = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=userData)
    act = ndb.StringProperty()
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

**Question #1**

Each user is uniquely identified by a unique code provided by the iOS app (Ex: AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-000000000000) which goes into the uuId entity property. Currently I'm also setting it as the Key Name of the "userData" kind. The idea is, in future queries, the iOS would send me the UUID and all I'll need is to query by Key which is super fast. But the trade off here is that index size goes way up because my keyName is approximately double the size of appengine generated ones.

So I guess my first question is, in this instance, what is the most efficient thing to do? Use a large key? Or use a slower read query?

**Question #2**
A similar trade off occurs in the responses table. Currently I'm concatenating the userData uuId & another key from another table to form a double size keyName for the responses entity that looks something like this:

```
AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-000000000000agtzfnNmYmFja2VuZHINCxIGc2hvZXMyGI56DA
```

I'm doing this because I know I'll be running alot of queries where I'll be asking: "Where pID==x & uuID==y", so I thought since I'll be doing alot of those, might as well condense it into one.

What do you guys think? Are the large keys a reasonable decision to make to have fast reads? Will my reads be faster?

**Update**
Another thing I'm considering is the following code:

```
import md5
m=md5.new()
lKey = "AAAAAAAA-AAAA-AAAA-AAAA-000000000000agtzfnNmYmFja2VuZHINCxIGc2hvZXMyGI56DA"
m.update(lKey)
print m.hexdigest()
```

Which returns a shorter unique ID: "569e1b8c6e469d703c8e7c2a739c5812". I know MD5 is only one way, so the only danger here is that I won't be able to go backwards, but I'm not sure that's a risk at all, so I actually may just go this route. What do you guys think?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The cost difference in storage between ids and names is minuscule compared to the cost of programming time. And I doubt the difference in query time is measurable. Structuring your data so that it can be queried efficiently does matter, but that's not a key name issue.

What might matter is whether a key name plus whatever cookies you're adding are big enough to cause an HTTP GET request to spill into another TCP/IP packet, since that'll impact your users who are on slower connections.

Answer (score 0):

Question #1) Definitely use a key lookup.  If you want to shorten the UUID, see this [possibly duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5535252/584846).

Question #2) Can you use an [ancestor query](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queries#ancestor)?  Store and retrieve your records using a [compound key](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities):

```
key = ndb.Key(userData, uuId, otherTable, otKey)
response = responses(parent=key)
qry = responses.query(ancestor=key)
```

The model constructor is described [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/modelclass?hl=en#Constructor).

Comment: Hey so I didn't want to use ancestor queries to avoid datastore contention! In this case there may be many responses per user so I thought it may be a bit crazy. I ended up sticking with the md5(uuid+pid) to create my key and it seems to be working okay!